# Alternate for Normalizer Transformation?

Tags: informatica

I have to implement Normalizer transformation logic without using Normalizer transformation in Informatica Powercenter. May i know all the ways i can implement with or without knowing the number of groups in input data.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the normalizer transformation that you can't use it?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the number of groups it's possible to implement this with expression transformation and variable ports. But it's tedious.
Without knowing the number of groups it won't be possible, I'm afraid. Or will require to create plenty of additional columns hoping it will be enough (but with no certanity).

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing using SQL. Override the below SQL in Source Qualifier and try loading into the target

The normalizer converts columns to rows in informatica. I have implemented the scenario using Oracle SQL's "Connect by Level"

```
    CREATE TABLE MARKS
    (
    NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    SUBJ1 NUMBER,
    SUBJ2 NUMBER,
    SUBJ3 NUMBER);

    INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES ('RAJ',70,80,90);
    INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES ('RAM',70,85,75);
    INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES ('RAVI',90,80,90);
    INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES ('RANI',80,80,95);
    INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES ('RAGHU',73,82,90);

    COMMIT;

    WITH DATA AS (SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3)
    SELECT NAME,DECODE(L,1,'PHYSICS',2,'CHEMISTRY',3, 'MATHS') AS SUBJECT , 
    DECODE(L ,1,SUBJ1,2,SUBJ2,3,SUBJ3) AS MARKS
    FROM MARKS, DATA 
    ORDER BY NAME;


NAME    SUBJECT     MARKS
raghu   physics     73
raghu   maths       90
raghu   chemistry   82
raj     physics     70
raj     chemistry   80
raj     maths       90
ram     physics     70
ram     maths       75
ram     chemistry   85
rani    chemistry   80
rani    physics     80
rani    maths       95
ravi    maths       90
ravi    physics     90
ravi    chemistry   80
```

The solution might not be dynamic but it serves your purpose.

Thanks 
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Transformation, I have used Java transformation in many instances to achieve results that a Normalizer would provide.